# Fastest way to collect data from db?

Tags: c#, performance, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

Work on C#.In my application several time  need to select\collect datafrom DB.Fro this task I do the bellow step

```
1)Write SP 
2)Execute the Sp 
3)Fill result to Generic collection(ORM)
4)By the collection Bind the control
```

I want to know is there any mechanism or technique \Advanced technique available help  to collect data from database.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you look at your store/table and tune performance there? For example look at your cluster-index to see it's good for your situation or not?, store procedure execute in a good way get only data that you need etc. I think it's better to tune database performance at your database. :)

Comment: When i again and again rapidly hit the db.then it's performance become bottleneck .What to do?i know sp is the best choice to collect data.several application access this db and there are several users

Comment: I use to fixed old code that loop through 1,000 int and execute 1 int per time to store procedure. I fix by send all 1,000 int separate by , then loop in store proc, this way performance is improve A LOT since it open connection and connect only once.

Comment: "i know sp is the best choice to collect data" - there really isn't much difference between an SP and a parameterised SQL command, for info. However: what is the actual problem you are trying to fix here?

Comment: marc Gravell thanks for reply.Try to increase my application performance.When i collect data from db to ado.net it's take much time and resource.I try to know is there any best process available .If yes then what is it?try to help to to get data from db in light process more than now.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i again and again rapidly hit the db.then it's performance become bottleneck .What to do?

It sounds like you should be caching some results. In a high load application, caching even for a few seconds can have a big impact on performance. There are a myriad of cache solutions out there; if this is a web app, the inbuilt http-context `.Cache` should be fine (.NET 4.0 adds `MemoryCache` to do the same more conveniently in non-web applications).

Re loading the data; you mention ORM - in our experience here, we find most ORMs indeed are a bottleneck for "hot" code paths - a subject I'm talking on in a few hours as it happens. Because we faced this problem, we wrote an intentionally simple but really *really* fast *micro-ORM*, [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). It isn't as feature rich as some full ORMs, but if you are trying to load data quick for display, it is ideal.

---

The other thing, of course, is to look at your query and improve the performance. Look in particular at the logical IO reads, and where they are coming from. It could well be that an extra index or a little denormalization could make a really big difference to your query performance.

Comment: +1 for MemoryCache , if you can add some more information about MemoryCache please thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ye, but the only exception is to use a DataReader or a DataTable.

For ex. datareader is usefull for limited view of rows from a large collection being retrieved.

However Datatable is important, if to apply functions on a complete collection of Data.

Plus there are different methods like connection pooling, localviews, indexes that will matter most when Data fetched is more than available Server resources.